# Error in lex program

Tags: c, flex-lexer, lex

I'm doing this program for understanding the normal functionality of lexical analyser. But when I'm compiling this program it's showing an error message::

"b.l:25: EOF encountered inside an action".

I don't understand why, as I Googled for reason and it said like some extra closing braces may be there in action part but it isn't the case.

```
%option noyywrap
%{
%}
%%
#include<.*> {fprintf(yyout,"\nPREPROCESSOR: %s",yytext);}
main {fprintf(yyout, "\nMAIN:%s",yytext);}
"void"|"int"|"for"|"if"|"return" {fprintf(yyout, "\n KEYWORD:%s",yytext);}
"{"|"}"|"("|")"|";"|"," {fprintf(yyout,"\n SPECIAL SYMBOLS:%s",yytext);}
"<"|">"|"=="|"<="|">=" {fprintf(yyout,"\nCONDITIONAL OPERATORS:%s",yytext);}
"==" {fprinf(yyout,"\nASSIGNMENT OPERATORS:%s",yytext);}
"++"|"--" {fprintf(yyout,"\nINC-DECR OPERATORS:%s",yytext);}
"printf".*|"scanf".* {fprintf(yyout,"\nINBUILT FUNCTIONS:"%s",yytext);}
[0-9]* {fprintf(yyout,"\nNUMBERS:%s",yytext);}
[a-zA-Z] [a-zA-Z0-9_]* {fprintf(yyout,"\nIDENTIFIERS:%s",yytext);}
%%
int main(int argc,char*argv[])
{
    yyin = fopen(argv[1],"r");
    yyout = fopen(argv[2],"w");
    yylex();
    fclose(yyin);
    fclose(yyout);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Your `printf` action has an unclosed string literal. You probably should remove the quote before `%s`.

It might be considered odd that flex allows multiline strings in actions, since standard C does not allow multiline strings. However, some C compilers do (or did) allow multiline string literals. In particular, gcc allowed them up to about v3.3, so flex assumes -- in this case, incorrectly -- that the multiline string literal is intentional.

---

It is also probably incorrect to recognize *any* token starting with `printf` and continuing to the end of the line. That will include things like `printfamily`, for example. If that was an attempt to include the *arguments* to printf without parsing them, it will fail in the case that the printf call is spread over more than one line, or is followed by another command on the same line.